# how to use LINQ to filter items in ViewData[ " " ] = new SelectList()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public partial class ProgramType
{
    public int PgmId { get; set; }
    public string PgmDescr { get; set; }
    public string PgmDescrLong { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NewProgram> NewProgram { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewForm> NewForm { get; set; }        
}
```

Which is populated with this data:

```
+-------+----------+--------------+
| PgmId | PgmDescr | PgmDescrLong |
+-------+----------+--------------+
| 1     | CERT     | Certificate  |
+-------+----------+--------------+
| 2     | DEG      | Degree       |
+-------+----------+--------------+
| 3     | DIP      | Diploma      |
+-------+----------+--------------+
```

Using EF Core, I have scaffolded a Controller for the NewProgram model. The Create() action defines the Value/Text fields of a dropdown list which displays items from the ProgramType table:

```
ViewData["ProgramType"] = new SelectList(_context.ProgramType, "PgmId", "PgmDescrLong");
```

But I want to limit the dropdown list to particular values depending on which Controller I'm working on. I can get this to limit the dropdown list to display only "Certificate":

```
ViewData["ProgramType"] = new SelectList(_context.ProgramType, "PgmId", "PgmDescrLong").Where(x => x.Text.Contains("Certificate"));
```

But I want it to show both "Certificate" and "Diploma". This does not work:

```
ViewData["ProgramType"] = new SelectList(_context.ProgramType, "PgmId", "PgmDescrLong").Where(x => x.Text.Contains("Certificate", "Diploma"));
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Instead of adding your where clause on the SelectList, filter your data first and then construct SelectList with the filtered data. The way you are doing it would fetch the entire dataset unnecessarily, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { "Certificate", "Diploma" };
ViewData["ProgramType"] = new SelectList(db.Programs, "PgmId", "PgmDescrLong").Where(x => strArray.Any(y => y == x.Text));
```

What you do is that create an array of string that you want to show on your dropdownlist.

From there, we will use that array to create a query that is like a `SQL IN` operator query just like this one:

```
Where(x => strArray.Any(y => y == x.Text));
```

Comment: While this should work, it is not the most efficient. Why not simply pre filter the data and then construct the SelectList with the filtered data? What you suggested will not result in SQL IN, it will be an in memory operation, I think.

Comment: Yes I agree, but in case of the post, I have limited info on the requirements of the OP and the other logic before the code posted above. But I can edit my post to add your inputs.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Regarding efficiency - there are only 5 records total in ProgramType. Thank you!